# Email notification for new Documents items

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, microsoft-teams

Could anybody tell me how to accomplish a very basic task:

In Microsoft Teams I have a document library, which reflects my SharePoint Online site document library.

When somebody adds a new item in that document library, I want an email message to be sent to the group members in Teams.

Trying MS Flow for this, it seems like it only works on Lists, and a document library is not a List (?).
Is there any workaround? Grateful for tips!

Comment: Not sure about SP Online, but on SP 2013 you could use an Alert.  Go to: Doc Library Settings>Alerts>new alert triggered on item creation.  I've not used MS Flow, I'd be surprised if it was not possible to use a workflow on a Document Library, it would be a massively regressive step is workflows were no longer possible on a Document Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well accomplish this using Flow.

- Select *When a file is created in a folder* as a trigger.
  [image]
- You have to provide the site address and Folder ID.[image]
- Next you can create an action for sending the alert email with proper recipients.

Comment: Oh thank you Veeraj! I tested this now and it is working! I did not see that menu at first (the menu you show up here), but came to another big menu with a lot of strange alternatives that sounded "almost" right but never worked. Thank you once again! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a simple SharePoint Designer Workflow for this. Use `SharePoint 2013 workflow`, put the `Email action` in it and set it to run after an item has been created. In the email action you can define all the recipients, subject and the body of the email message.

Comment: Hi Damjan! SharePoint Designer? Hummm... almost forgotten about, will try it out soon and let you know, thank you! :-)